# Why does Matlab's cellfun function not honor imports? How to propagate import statement to anonymous functions?

Tags: matlab, oop, import, cell-array

I want to test a cell array of objects for objects of a certain class. 
I organize my files in packages and use `import` statements to make my code shorter.

The problem: `cellfun(@(o) isa(o,'MyClassName'),myCellArray)` seems to ignore the import declaration, returning `false` for cell array elements where invoking `isa(myCellArray{i}, 'MyClassName')` would yield `true`.

How can I make `cellfun` honor my `import` statements?

**EDIT:**  Might the import statement not propagate to the anonymous function inside `cellfun`? If yes, how can I archieve this?

### Minimal (Not) Working Example

Files:

```
myfun.m
+pkg/
+pkg/MyClass.m
```

---

myfun.m:

```
% cat <<"%EOF" > myfun.m # paste into shell if on UNIX
function myfun()
    import pkg.MyClass;
    o{1} = MyClass();

    x = cellfun(@(d) isa(d,'MyClass'),o);
    fprintf('cellfun: %d\n',x);

    b = isa(o{1},'MyClass');
    fprintf('direct: %d\n',b);

    fprintf('classes of o: \n');
    cellfun(@class, o,'UniformOutput',false)
end
%EOF
```

---

+pkg/MyClass.m:

```
% mkdir "+pkg"; cat <<"%EOF" >"+pkg/MyClass.m" # paste to shell if on UNIX
classdef MyClass
end
%EOF
```

---

My Output is:

```
>> myfun
cellfun: 0
direct: 1
classes of o: 
ans = 
    'pkg.MyClass'
```

If I move `MyClass.m` to the same directory as `myfun.m` and remove the `import ...` line in `myfun.m`:

```
>> myfun
cellfun: 1
direct: 1
classes of o: 
ans = 
    'MyClass'
>>
```